# Doing piecewise regression using a binary independent variable as breakpoint in R

Tags: r, piecewise

First time trying to use the 'segmented' package in R and have some (probably stupid) questions.

I am implementing a piecewise regression in R, what I am trying to do is like this:

```
y <- c(621, 552, 581, 549, 563, 633, 531, 348, 323, 285, 282, 303, 192, 281, 466, 969, 1549, 1264, 447, 367)
x1 <- c(727, 689, 702, 646, 677, 798, 832, 377, 366, 351, 316, 333, 291, 526, 466, 1488, 1549, 1431, 696, 687)
x2 <- c(10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8, 8, 8, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10)
x3 <- rep(c(0,1),10)

df <- data.frame(cbind(y,x1,x2,x3))

fit.lm <- lm(y~x1+x2, data=df)
piecewise <- segmented(fit.lm, seg.Z = ~x3, psi=0.5)
```

I hope to do a two-segment piecewise regression in which I can use variable x3, a binary variable, to break the model into two segments - one segment with x3=0, and another with x3=1.

With that in mind, I therefore used 0.5 as my estimated break-point.  However, I got an error message like this:

```
 Error: at least one coef is NA: breakpoint(s) at the boundary? (possibly with many x-values replicated)
```

Two questions:

1. Given what I intended to do, does the code make sense?
2. What's the possible cause of the error and how can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I wonder if the issue is that x only takes values of 0 and 1. Maybe there just isn't enough variance on x3 for the estimation of the break point to work? In any case, if you want compare estimates across only two sets, it might make more sense to use interaction terms for x3 and the other covariates instead of treating it as a break point.

Comment: @ulfelder, thanks for your response.  I guess I will try to implement my idea manually.